# Detect Blackberry Z3, Z10, Z30 camera & GPS in Webworks 10 2.2?

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry, camera, gps

I'm using WebWorks 2.2 to develop an HTML5 + javascript application for the Blackberry Z3, Z10 and Z30.

On starting my app, I would like it to detect if a camera is available. Our IT department may or may not disable the camera on selected phones.

I would also like to detect if the GPS is available.

Can someone please help with how to do this via a cordova/webworks plugin and Javascript?

Thanks in advance,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this tutorial will help you:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

> getUserMedia() has been supported since Chrome 21, Opera 18, and
>   Firefox 17.

Be aware that not every browser supports it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

But you just have to try it out.

(HTML5 available mobile-devices: http://mobilehtml5.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  getUserMedia() API does indeed work, now it's asking me whether I want to use the front or the back camera. I now need to see if there's a way of detecting a camera without this prompt appearing.  But it's progress!   If I find a solution, I will mark your answer as reply.

Comment: OK looked further, the getUserMedia() doesn't have any parameters that let me check for the camera being enabled. So unfortunately it's not suitable for use.